# Swift create a class using a delegate

Tags: swift, core-location

This might be talked about somewhere but I can not find any articles that talk about this. I am trying to write a class that wraps around apple's native CoreLocation API. My goal is to be able to call something like `LocationTrack.getDPS` and have that return gps coordinates, from the locationManager delegate.

```
class LocationTrack: CLLocationManagerDelegate  {

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
            {
                locationManager = CLLocationManager()
                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
        }

  func getDPS(completion: @escaping (result: [CLLocation]) -> () {

       //How to get below delegate response into this function?

    }

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

      print(locations)

}


    }
```

Comment: Why don't you create a property for CLLocationManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define property to capture your completion handler:

```
private var handler: (([CLLocation]) -> Void)?
```

And have `getDPS` save it and start updating locations:

```
func getDPS(_ completion: @escaping ([CLLocation]) -> Void) {
    handler = completion
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

And then your `didUpdateLocations` can call that closure:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    handler?(locations)
    handler = nil
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

---

Pulling all of that together, maybe something like:

```
class LocationTrack: NSObject {
    private lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()   // perhaps `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` is better?
        return locationManager
    }()

    private var handler: (([CLLocation]) -> Void)?

    func getDPS(_ completion: @escaping ([CLLocation]) -> Void) {
        handler = completion
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

extension LocationTrack: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        handler?(locations)
        handler = nil
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Clearly you can add your own error handling and what have you, but hopefully this illustrates the idea of saving the closure in a property and calling it when you get your delegate call-back.

Comment: This is great. Can you explain the need for `NSObject` in class definition and defining the `locationManager` as `lazy`?

Comment: @Nick - I subclass `NSObject` because `CLLocationManager` is Objective-C, where all objects are `NSObject` subclasses. The `delegate` of the `CLLocationManager` must be `NSObject` subclass. Try removing `NSObject` inheritance and you’ll get a compiler warning where it attempts to set itself as the `delegate`. Regarding `lazy`, I do that because I want to use a closure to initialize `locationManager` (keeps code nice & tidy), but I can’t reference `self` in the closure unless it’s lazy (i.e. instantiated later when first accessed rather than when `LocationTrack` is first instantiated).